# Solve multiple-source multiple-destination graph game

Tags: algorithm, graph, artificial-intelligence, game-theory

I'm trying to categorize the graph problem below or find hints to its solution.

There is an (adjacency) matrix that can contain 3 types of elements: units, points and simple terrain.

Terrain has no specific meaning.

Units have a position (x,y defined by the matrix) and a number of points that they can acquire.
Points have a position (x,y defined by the matrix).
The cost of acquiring a point is the Manhattan distance between a point and unit.
Each point can only be acquired by one unit.

The problem is: how to find the minimal cost configuration of units acquiring points, such that all resources of the units are depleted?

Example:
u1 can acquire 3 points
u2 can acquire 2 points

```
p1 n n p2  
n u1 n p3  
p4 n n n  
n n u2 p5
```

One of the optimal solutions is:

```
u1 = p1, p2, p4  
cost(u1)=2+3+2=7  
u2 = p3, p5  
cost(u2)=3+1=4  
Total cost = 11
```

(minimal for this configuration)

Notes:
I have tried solving this with uniform cost search and A*(with a simple heuristic), but even for small sizes of the matrix, I get a very high number of states and run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reduce it to [min-cost-max-flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-cost_flow_problem) problem.

Let's make a network. Assign a vertex to each unit and each point. For each pair (unit, point) add an oriented edge with capacity 1 and cost equal to corresponding Manhattan distance. Add a sink, connect it to all units. Add a trap and connect all points to it.

Assign the following values of cost and capacity:
**cap( u, v ) = 1**, if there is an edge from u to v 
**cost( u, v ) = 0**, if u = sink or v = trap; otherwise it's equal to manhattan distance from unit u to point v.

Now if we find min-cost-max-flow in this network, it will be the solution to your problem. Why ? Because we found the minimal cost way to move a unit of flow from each "unit" vertex to some "point" vertex, which is equivalent to the original problem.

Comment: What values of supply/demand should be assigned to units, points, the sink and the trap?
Should units have the supply equal to the number of points they can acquire, and the points have a demand of 1 (ie -1 supply)?

Comment: @Placinta: not sure what you mean buy supply/demand. Each unit has an edge incoming from the sink with cap = 1, meaning that point should go to exactly one point. The same for each edge point -> sink, meaning that any point can be obtained by at most one unit.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the solution you purposed, and indeed it gives the optimal solution!
But sadly, for slightly bigger matrices it takes too much time to compute. Perhaps the implementation is at fault.